# Regular Expression (REGEX) to match X-SPAM-SCORE

Tags: regex, filter, spam, spamassassin

As a domain owner I have been struggling inevitably with spam, I wrote a REGEX expression to establish an acceptable level on the X-SPAM-SCORE, I know that CPANEL provides some "filters" for establishing this but in my case I found that my expression would suit my needs better, I am sharing it to save some one some time and as the means of documenting it.

Answer (score 0):

So in the CPANEL you need to add this expression to "***match***" and "***message headers***".

> ^(X-Spam-Score:)\s(-[0-9]*)?(28|34|35|36|37|38|39|[4-9]\d+|\d{3,})(.*[0-9]?[0-9]?)?$

Just copy the full expression and it will help you on filtering your SPAM mail.

I do not claim to be an expert on REGEX and I am sure there might be a million other ways to attack this need, If you have something constructive to say, please be my guest and welcome.

Cheers

EN